# Uncaught TypeError: unknown stream type "undefined" when using React's 'activedirectory' module

Tags: reactjs, react-native, active-directory

I have this simple React component to handle Active Directory authentication:

```
import React from 'react';
import ActiveDirectory from 'activedirectory';

export default class ActiveDirectoryComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    authResponse: undefined
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    var config = {
      url: 'ldap://compandomain.com:389',
      baseDN: 'dc=domainname,dc=com',
      username: 'user',
      password: 'pass'
    };

    var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);
    var username = 'john.smith@domain.com';
    var password = 'password';

    ad.authenticate(username, password, function (err, auth) {
      if (err) {
        this.setState({ authResponse: { error: JSON.stringify(err) } });
        return;
      }

      if (auth) {
        this.setState({ authResponse: auth });
      } else {
        console.log('Authentication failed!');
        this.setState({ authResponse: { authFailed: true } });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.authResponse) {
      return <div>Authenticating....</div>;
    }
    if (this.state.authResponse.error) {
      return <div>{this.state.authResponse.error}</div>
    }
    if (this.state.authResponse.authFailed) {
      return <div>Authentication Failed</div>
    }
    return <div>.....</div>
  }
}
```

When I attempt to use this component:

```
 import ActiveDirectoryComponent from '../components/ActiveDirectoryAuthentication';
```

My App does not load and I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: unknown stream type "undefined"
    at Logger.addStream (bunyan.js?a10b:620)
    at eval (bunyan.js?a10b:470)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at new Logger (bunyan.js?a10b:469)
    at Function.createLogger (bunyan.js?a10b:1618)
    at Object.eval (activedirectory.js?f995:16)
    at eval (990:1836)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1)
    at e (bundle.js:1)
    at eval (index.js?048a:1)
```

Any idea what needs to setup for bunyan to properly have a stream?
This seems to me like an issue in the 'activedirectory' module, as I think it should properly create stream through bunyan. But I am not entirely sure, since I am very new to React.

Update (10/31/2018): the 'activedirectory' module works perfectly in Javascript. The issue above is only seen in React. I had to write a separate Javascript app to interact with activedirectory and use it from my React app. While this works as a workaround, it would be nice if the above issue is fixed so that all of the code is in React.

Comment: Bummer, also having this issue using vue.js. Any updates?

Comment: yeah it is a weird issue. For my case, i just created created an Javascript app that interacts with active-directory. I works perfectly with mostly the same code above. Then I linked to the javascript app from my React component. I am positive this is an issues with React/Activedirectory

Answer (score 2):

There's an open pull request on the activedirectory module on Github which addresses this issue: [https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory/pull/150/files](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory/pull/150)

I tried it locally and it resolves the issue. Hopefully the PR will be merged eventually.